# Group and filter records and find max in a huge table in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, grouping

I have a table with 4,000,000 of records and growing every day.

```
Prices(Contract INT, Period DATE, Date DATE, PriceValue FLOAT)
```

I need to filter Prices by **Date** (@dateFrom / @dateTo is user input) and find max **Date** price for every unique **Contract/Period**

First, I've started with:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM  
  (
    SELECT [ContractId], [Period], MAX(p.Date) AS MaxDate FROM Prices p  WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE (@dateFrom IS NULL OR p.[Date] >= @dateFrom) AND p.[Date] <= @dateTo)
    GROUP BY [ContractId], [Period]
  ) md      
  INNER JOIN Prices p  WITH (NOLOCK) ON md.ContractId = p.ContractId AND md.PERIOD  = p.PERIOD AND md.MaxDate = p.Date
  WHERE (@dateFrom IS NULL OR p.[Date] >= @dateFrom) AND p.[Date] <= @dateTo)
```

It worked ok for 2-3 weeks date range, but its often when 1 year of data is requested. It takes up to 30-60 sec...

Then I tried ROW_NUMBER() approach, but it wa super slow...

And finally, I switche to EF lamba, that generates following query (cleared it a bit)

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1]......
    FROM   (SELECT 
        @toDate AS [p__linq__0], 
        @fromDate AS [p__linq__1], 
        [Distinct1].....
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent1].[ContractId] AS [ContractId], 
            [Extent1].[Period] AS [Period], 
            FROM [dbo].[Prices] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[ContractId] IN ... AND ([Extent1].[Date] <= @toDate))
        )  AS [Distinct1] ) AS [Project2]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project3].[Id] AS [Id], [Project3].[ContractId] AS [ContractId], [Project3].[Period] AS [Period], [Project3].[Date] AS [Date], [Project3].[PriceValue] AS [PriceValue])
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent2].....
            FROM [dbo].[Prices] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent2].[ContractId] IN ... AND ([Project2].[Period] = ...)
        )  AS [Project3]
        ORDER BY [Project3].[Date] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
```

Outer apply worked a bit faster but still 20-30 secs.

Indexes on the table

```
CREATE INDEX FilteredPricesOnlyLast
ON TradeBlotterDevPoc.dbo.Prices (ContractId, PERIOD, Date)
GO


CREATE INDEX IDX_Latest
ON TradeBlotterDevPoc.dbo.Prices (ContractId, PERIOD)
INCLUDE (Date)
GO
```

MSSQL Studio and Azure do not give any indexes recommendations.

**So, question**
Is there any way to complete this task x5 times or more faster than basic GROUP BY or OUTER APPLY?
Probably with any other kind of tricky SQL query?
Or there any known practices of data preprocessing?

Comment: On some of your sub selects on the larger tables before joining insert the data into a temp table (intermediate step) to reduce the number of records in your JOIN on the other tables.  It makes it multiple steps but can speed things up quite a bit by separating out some of the logic and then only joining/querying other logic on smaller subset of data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create partitions of your table (for year in this example)

```
DECLARE @YearStart INT, @YearEnd INT
SELECT @yearStart = MIN(Year(Date)), @yearEnd = Year(GETDATE()) 
FROM Prices
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE @YearStart < @YearEnd -- keep current year in your original table
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = '
    SELECT * INTO 
    Prices' + CAST(@YearStart AS VARCHAR) + '
    FROM Prices
    WHERE Date < DateFromParts(@YearStart + 1, 1, 1)

    DELETE Prices WHERE DATE < DateFromParts(@YearStart + 1, 1, 1)
    '
    sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Year INT', @Year = @YearStart

    SET @SQL = '
    CREATE INDEX FilteredPricesOnlyLast' + CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR) + '
    ON TradeBlotterDevPoc.dbo.Prices' + CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR) + ' (ContractId, PERIOD, Date)'
    EXEC(@SQL)

    SET @YearStart = @YearStart + 1
END
```

Then you can use the CTE and Outer APPLY, use union all if you need to use more than one partition

```
;WITH Periods AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ContractID, Period
    FROM Prices 
    WHERE (@dateFrom IS NULL OR p.[Date] >= @dateFrom) AND p.[Date] <= @dateTo)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT ContractID, Period
    FROM Prices2018 
    WHERE (@dateFrom IS NULL OR p.[Date] >= @dateFrom) AND p.[Date] <= @dateTo)
)
SELECT 
    Periods.ContractID, Period.Period, A.Date, A.Price
FROM Periods
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Date, Price 
    FROM Prices 
    WHERE ContractID = Periods.ContractID AND Period = Periods.Period
    AND (@dateFrom IS NULL OR p.[Date] >= @dateFrom) AND p.[Date] <= @dateTo)
    ORDER BY Date DESC
) A
```